# (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, proguard

I've got a xamarin.form PCL.

App build find in DEBUG and working.
I wanted to enable "ProGuard" feature.

but got the following error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

What I've done:

- Set Max Heap Size: 1G to 5G.
- Enabled/Disabled Multi-Dex
- Switch between: SDK Assemblies only /  SDK and user Assemblies
- Updated to the latest ProGuard and kept the latest configuration from the old ProGuard.
- Updated SDK Manager.

  - jdk1.8.0_111
- Set Xamarin Diagnostics output vervosity: Diagnostic.

Unable to find any other error.

Android Project contain
-proguard.cfg

```
# General Android
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

I checked line 2053 in Xamarin.android.Common.targets:

```
 <Proguard
    Condition="'$(AndroidEnableProguard)' == 'True' and '$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)' != ''"
    ProguardJarPath="$(ProguardJarPath)"
    AndroidSdkDirectory="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)"
    JavaToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
    ProguardToolPath="$(ProguardToolPath)"
    ToolExe="$(ProguardToolExe)"
    UseProguard="$(UseProguard)"
    JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
    ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
    AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)"
    ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg"
    ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration="$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)"
    ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg"
    ProguardConfigurationFiles="$(ProguardConfigFiles)"
    JavaLibrariesToEmbed="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompile);@(_InstantRunJavaReference)"
    ExternalJavaLibraries="@(AndroidExternalJavaLibrary)"
    DoNotPackageJavaLibraries="@(_ResolvedDoNotPackageAttributes)"
    ProguardJarOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"
    EnableLogging="$(ProguardEnableLogging)"
    DumpOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\dump.txt"
    PrintSeedsOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\seeds.txt"
    PrintUsageOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\usage.txt"
    PrintMappingOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\mapping.txt"
     />
```

Compile using latest version
Min: 23
Target:Use Compile SDK Version

VS2015 NDK and SDK reference are correct since I can generate a build in DEBUG.

Verbose: Diagnostic

```
3>C:\TEST_TFS\XXXX.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\AWClient-SDK.dll : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
    3>C:\TEST_TFS\XXXX.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\LocalDb\DatabaseConnection_Android.cs(22,30,22,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
    3>C:\TEST_TFS\XXXX.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\PCL\PlatformStyleBO.cs(19,24,19,44): warning CS0169: The field 'PlatformStyleBO._buttonHeightRequest' is never used
    3>  APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid -> C:\TEST_TFS\XXXX.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\bin\Release\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid.dll
    3>C:\TEST_TFS\SSSSS.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
    3>C:\TEST_TFS\SSSSS.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
    3>C:\TEST_TFS\SSSSS.XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX\XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-branch-no-auth\APP.XXXXX.XXXX\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid\APP.XXXXX.XXXX.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
    3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

*Proguard* can be a bit of a pain. The usual symptom is something like

> java exited with code 1

Steps that worked for me (I had these notes stored in my solution because it just wasn't obvious). Lifted from [this site](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-proguard-and-xamarin-android-eea5a56bc316)

1. Download the latest version of *Proguard*
2. Find where your *Android SDK* is installed (something like /android-sdk/tools/proguard”). To find the sdk go to `Tools->Options->Xamarin`
3. Swap out the old version of *Proguard*, with the new one. To do this rename the current folder to something like “Proguard-pointless” and copy your new one into the tools folder.
4. Be sure to rename the folder for the new version to just be “proguard”.
5. Make sure that any configuration files are also copied across into the new *Proguard* folder. For me this was `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, `proguard-android.txt`, and `proguard-project.txt`.
6. Add a new file to the root of your *Android* project called `proguard.cfg`

   NOTE : Because *Xamarin* is smart, it saves this new file in `UTF-8` with `BOM`, **you will need to change this**. Probably best to create the file in notepad, and then include it in your program. **This is required because Proguard will not read the file unless it is in UTF-8 encoding.**
7. In VS *Right Click* on the file and select *Properties*. For Build Action, select **ProguardConfiguration**.
8. Add relevant `keep` or `dontwarn` clauses to the file without the quotes (it depends on your warnings) , for example it could be something like this...

   - "-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**"
   - "-keep class com.google.android.gms.**"
9. Once you have done those steps, try a build once again.
10. Hopefully this time it will be more successful. If it is not successful, **check your build output** and see what warnings and notes *Proguard* is giving you.

From this stage it is a matter of identifying what modifications you need to make to your custom *Proguard* file, once that works the build will be successful.

**Update**

> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the
>   $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1)

I know these are just warnings, however have tried what it says. I.e updated your target framework version for your projects ?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've actually done all this. download, rename, copied, kept the config, added proguard and made sure it was UTF by going to NotePad. Can't seem to output any error when it hits Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,3). I'll try again carefully following your steps.

Comment: Tried again and no luck. I get NO proguard error at all! 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: Can you look further up the output sometimes there is clues in the liog. Also you could try putting  the log details on a higher setting

Comment: @PJB udpated, lets try this out and see what happens, it might get us moving forward a little